# Angular Style Guide 04-11 - Use shared pipe inside core component

Tags: angular

So I read the [Style Guide of Angular](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) > Core Feature Module > Style Guide 04-11:

> **Do** gather application-wide, single-use components in the CoreModule. Import it once (in the AppModule) when the app starts and never import it anywhere else. (e.g. NavComponent and SpinnerComponent).
>
> **Why?** Real world apps can have several single-use components (e.g., spinners, message toasts, and modal dialogs) that appear only in the AppComponent template. They are not imported elsewhere so they're not shared in that sense. Yet they're too big and messy to leave loose in the root folder.

I can relate to that. Although, I've stumbled across a small issue that makes me wonder if this style guide is recommended.

I've got some pipes that exist inside my `SharedModule` that I need to use inside a `CoreModule`'s singular component.

I thought about 2 alternatives:

- **Import SharedModule inside CoreModule** - But then there will be lots of irrelevant components/ directives/pipes that I don't need.
- **Declare the desired pipes inside AppModule** - But then the whole idea of separation.

Is there another recommended alternative?

Comment: What do you mean by CoreModules singular component?

Comment: @TheUnreal I mean components that are being used just once. For example - a HeaderComponent. This component is only being used just once. Unlike CommonComponent that is being used multiple times in multiple modules.

Comment: If your `SharedModule` has to much in it, you can split it. one for Material modules, one for Dialogs, one for Pipes, etc .. all depends on the amount of content your application holds.. Not sure I understand your question

Comment: @Stavm it's not that I don't want to import SharedModule just because it's big. It's because it feels odd to import the entire shared module just for one or two pipes. But I get your point. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Style Guide is not something you MUST follow, is only a collection of suggestions that works in 99% of projects.

Regarding the first solution (importing SharedModule inside CoreModule) you have to consider that the code will be tree-shaked so only the used code will be compiled.
On the other hand for very huge applications might makes sense also to split the SharedModule in smaller pieces (but I'd avoid it).

Comment: I guess I'll have to let the tree shaking do it's thing. When the app will be larger, I might split the SharedModule. Thanks.